# Extend existing dynamic project with Spring REST

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I need to add REST support in existing JSP/Servlets project. I want to use Spring because of its community and its possibilities. I have to implement several features and I believe Spring can help me to achieve it

1. To implement REST with existing web.xml with path /rest/*
2. To make REST consume and produce both JSON and XML. XML is default
3. To make REST use existing authentication mechanism

I didn't find in internet any post which cover first two statement. There is many Spring boot examples with autoconfiguring and spring-mvc 3.x without REST

For 3rd goal about authentication I think I can create custom annotation for methods like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/rest/greeting")
@MyAuthCheck(group="admin")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
...
```

Current code is presented here https://github.com/anteastra/spring-rest-jsp. Third commit
I did following steps

1. Created dynamic project in Eclipse
2. Added spring libraries for project, the list of libraries I had got from Maven Spring Rest tutorials:

   ```
   aopalliance-1.0  
   commons-logging-1.2  
   jstl-1.2  
   spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE  
   spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE  
   spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE  
   spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE  
   spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE  
   spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE  
   spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE
   ```
3. Added DispatcherServlet to `web.xml`

   ```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
4. Added RestController

   ```
   package com.app;
   import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
   import com.domain.Greeting;

   @RestController
   public class GreetingController {

       private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
       private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

       @RequestMapping("/greeting")
       public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
           return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                           String.format(template, name));
       }

   }
   ```
5. Added rest-servlet in web.xml for component scan

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

   <bean id="viewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
       <property name="viewClass"
           value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
   ```

There is some additional things in code related to Spring-MVC not REST part. For example there is one `@Controller`.

Then I start tomcat it log says that everything mapped correctly:

```
 дек 13, 2015 8:04:34 PM  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
 INFO: Mapped URL path [/greeting] onto handler 'greetingController'
 дек 13, 2015 8:04:34 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
 INFO: Mapped URL path [/greeting.*] onto handler 'greetingController'
 дек 13, 2015 8:04:34 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
 INFO: Mapped URL path [/greeting/] onto handler 'greetingController'
```

But then I perform GET request to /rest/greeting I got:

> HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/jsp/greeting.jsp

I found somethere that it is because of missed @ResponseBody annotation.
I thought that this annotation not needed in Spring 4.x, but I added 
`@ResponseBody` to check:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public @ResponseBody Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

There was '"HTTP Status 406, The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers'.

Ok, I modifyed @RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", produces={"application/json", "application/xml"}, consumes={"application/json", "application/xml"})
```

But I still have HTTP Status 406
[in soapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hONQb.png)

How can I achive my goals using Spring 4.x?

Comment: Do you have any Jackson libraries as dependencies?

Comment: which one do you mean? I tried several - no effect.
For example, I added jackson-mapper-asl, as said here http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/